# Using innerHTML property to display content of another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to set the innerHTML of one of my elements to the content of another html file that just displays plain text. Is this possible? The way I'm thinking of it is as follows, but obviously it will just set the text to that quote directly instead of displaying the contents of the file.

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = "directory/file.html"
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do an `ajax` call to get the files contents and put them in the html on success.

```
var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined' ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xhr.open('get', 'directory/file.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    } 
}
xhr.send();
```

Or using jQuery, the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is made for you:

```
$( "#myElement" ).load( "directory/file.html" );
```

Comment: I suggest you to invert the suggestion order of your answer, since the OP didn't add jQuery in his tags :)

Comment: You're right and I did, but the question wasn't even tagged with javascript before I did it... @Buzinas

Comment: I haven't learned jQuery or Ajax yet, but it looks like I'm about to. Thanks for the info. Would it just simply not be possible to do in html, or would it just be too much work?

Comment: No, it's not possible with html only @user2789945, but if you put the javascript snippet inside a script tag right before the closing body tag in your html it will work. Only change the url.

Comment: Good, @baao, I haven't seen that he didn't put the javascript tag before. Upvoted your answer! :)

Comment: Woah this is faster than a simple innerHTML call I was using to append a template.

Comment: This is powerful stuff. No need to keep reloading my sidebar. I'll rewrite my code around this and do away with almost half the files I was using. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `iframe` tag:

```
<iframe id="myHtml" src="directory/file.html"></iframe>
```

You can easily change the `iframe`'s content by simply change it's `src` attribute (it will automatically update):

```
document.getElementById('myHtml').src = 'other_file.html';
```

If you also want to use `innerHTML` to display html from string, you can use the `iframe`'s `srcdoc` attribute (overrides the `src` attribute):

```
document.getElementById('myHtml').srcdoc = '<div><p>Some HTML</p></div>';
```

Comment: while the other answer is technically more correct, this suits my implementation better for the time being, thanks!

Comment: Why this answer is technically less-correct than the other answer? I think this one is also concise and does the same thing at the bottom-line. So why should one bother with the ajax or jquery for such a simple task?