# Return specific html doc depending on the query parameters in the url

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to selectively display different html documents depending on the query parameters in the url.

If the query parameter in the URL is "track" I want to load track.html. If it is "artist" I want to load artist.html.

I have a small script that will determine the queries and return them in a list.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let queries = []
for (const [key, value] of urlParams) {
  queries.push(key);
}

console.log(queries)
```

I want the code to be something like this:

```
if (queries === ["track"]) {
  // load track.html

  // I was thinking something like:

  document.querySelector("#body").innerHTML = /track.html
  
}else {
  // load artist.html

}
```

Comment: Are you using ajax?

Comment: no, i am not...

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938168/using-innerhtml-property-to-display-content-of-another-html-file/32938450